# Setting metadata options for ouput GeoTIFF when using gdalwarp?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, metadata

I'm reprojecting and changing the format of a vrt to GeoTIFF and can't seem to control metadata options with gdalwarp.

Other tools like gdal_translate have the -mo option to specify metadata options but gdalwarp doesn't.

In this case, the original .dem (CDED format) have a metadata option that says `AREA_OR_POINT = POINT` and the output GeoTIFF, using gdalwarp, defaults to `AREA_OR_POINT = AREA`.

To be honest, I don't know the significance or importance of the `AREA_OR_POINT` metadata option, but just like matching input to output as much as I can.

The command I'm using is:
`gdalwarp -of GTiff \
          -ot Int16 \
          -s_srs "EPSG:4269" -t_srs "EPSG:3005" \
          -tr 15 15 -r bilinear \
          -wm 4096 -multi \
          -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 \
          -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS \
          -srcnodata "-32767" \
          mosaic_dem_cded_4269.vrt dem_3005.tiff`

Comment: PS You may want to check whether your rasters line up correctly if you manually set `AREA_OR_POINT=POINT `, GDAL *may* (not sure, never tested) adjust the georeferencing by 1/2 a pixel when it sets `AREA_OR_POINT=AREA` - https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc33_gtiff_pixelispoint

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was gonna post a question asking what that metadata option did and why it was important but that explains it. I noticed the output VRTs dont have it listed in the metadata or the output of the gdalinfo command so I'll be curious to see if gdalwarp ignores it from the source data and does some shifting in the output vrt's by defaulting to AREA_OR_POINT = AREA in the background silently. For reference, the source data is at ftp://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/175624/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can warp to VRT then translate to your output GeoTIFF.  This will also avoid [issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89444/file-size-inflation-normal-with-gdalwarp) that can arise when using `gdalwarp` to output compressed files.

```
gdalwarp -of VRT \
          -ot Int16 \
          -s_srs "EPSG:4269" -t_srs "EPSG:3005" \
          -tr 15 15 -r bilinear \
          -wm 4096 -multi \
          -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS \
          -srcnodata "-32767" \
          mosaic_dem_cded_4269.vrt dem_3005.vrt

gdal_translate -mo "your metadata" dem_3005.vrt dem_3005.tif
```

You could also pipe the output of gdalwarp to gdal_translate using the STREAMABLE_OUTPUT=YES creation option and the /vsistdout/ and /vsistdin/ virtual filenames (GDAL 2x):

```
 gdalwarp -of GTiff \
          -ot Int16 \
          -co STREAMABLE_OUTPUT=YES \
          -s_srs "EPSG:4269" -t_srs "EPSG:3005" \
          -tr 15 15 -r bilinear \
          -wm 4096 -multi \
          -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS \
          -srcnodata "-32767" \
          mosaic_dem_cded_4269.vrt /vsistdout/ | gdal_translate /vsistdin/ dem_3005.tif
```

Notes: you must use a trailing slash for /vsistdout/ and /vsistdin/ (i.e not /vsistdout and /vsistdin) and I have *no* idea if streaming is compatible with multithreaded warping...

Comment: Ah cool, never considered `gdalwarp -of VRT`. This is perfect because it avoids the creation of large intermediary/scratch datasets in this chain.

Comment: @SaultDon see edit for another option